# Access Opened Java IO Streams from Another Java Application

Tags: java, io, stream

I am working on a game with multiplayer support. The connection between the client and server is not encrypted (I'm going to add it soon). Is there a way in Java that I could connect to the already opened IO streams and inject packets?

Comment: No. Use separate connections for every client.

Comment: Every client has its own InputStream and OutputStream. I was wondering if I could connect through that stream from another program and inject packets.

Comment: InputStream and OutputStream are just objects inside JVM memory. They can be accessed by any class inside that JVM, and cannot be accessed from another instance of JVM.

Comment: Isn't a port opened in the connection and another program can use that port to send data?

Comment: depends on what you mean with "another program". If this is a class loaded in the same JVM (process), then it can. The class loaded in another process - can not, just because it has no access to the address space of the first process, where the opened port resides.